# what is equivalent of java interface.class in typescript

Tags: javascript, java, typescript

writing one java code in typescript. In Java I have code like below:

`Class<?> meta = Object.class;`
and

`meta = Processor.class; // Processor is an interface`

So what can be equivalent of `.class` in Type Script? Specially in interface case, if Processor would be a class, then I can simply remove `.class` path and this is working for me so far.

**Updated Example:**

```
public interface ObjectProcessor {}
public interface StreamCloser {}

public interface Registry {
  void register(Object value, Object metadata);
}

public class RegistryImpl implements Registry {
  void register(Object value, Object metadata) {}
}


RegistryImpl registry = new RegistryImpl();


Object value = ?; //any value
Class<?> meta = Object.class;

if (value instanceof ObjectProcessor) {
  meta = ObjectProcessor.class;
} else if (value instanceof StreamCloser) {
  meta = StreamCloser.class;
}

registry.register(value, meta);
```

Answer (score 0):

The class itself. Unlike Java, classes are functions, and functions are first-class, thus you can pass them around.

```
  const meta = Object;
```

As Java is statically typed, `.class` can provide an entry point for reflection and provides you with informations about the class (properties, methods). JS is different.

Comment: For Object.class is clear, but what about `interface.class`. I don't think Processor.class is same like Object. So what can do here ?

Comment: @9me typescript interfaces do not exist at runtime. Thus, they can't be stored in variables.

Comment: that I also know that interface will not exist on runtime. that y I asked this question that in java its possiable, but in TS just because of this face what should I do if i want something like `interface.class` ?

Comment: I can't think of a case were you want that. You can derive every information you need from the instance itslef.

Comment: Can you please explain your suggestion little bit more ? thank you

Comment: Difficult without an actual usecase

Comment: I updated example hopefully this will help you to explain my problem.

Comment: You can't just transfer code from a statucally typed to a dynamic language line by line. You got an XY problem here

Comment: But can you tell me y do we need interface.class ? Can you please give me any example ?

Comment: I don't know java.